# How can I use an environmental variable to create a dump with PostgreSQL? I found a solution but I don't know why it doesn't work the other way

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I want to create a dump of my psql database. I tried following code

```
sudo docker exec -t db pg_dump -c -U "$DATABASE_USER" > $BACKUP_DIR/backup$DATE.sql
```

but I only get an error that it can't connect to the database "root"

```
pg_dump: error: connection to database "root" failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

and that's good, but I didn't define root inside of $DATABASE_USER, so I wonder where it comes from.
After a little try and error I found a working code.

```
sudo docker exec -t db pg_dump -c -U $(sudo docker exec -it db /bin/sh -c 'printf $DATABASE_USER') > $BACKUP_DIR/backup$DATE.sql
```

I defined $DATABASE_USER in the .env file and put it inside of my compose file.

```
env_file:
    ./.env
```

Edit:
I changed my code a little bit, so I can change the Username without having to switch the database

```
sudo docker exec -t db pg_dump -c -U $(sudo docker exec -it db /bin/sh -c 'printf $DATABASE_USER') -d $(sudo docker exec -it db /bin/sh -c 'printf $DATABASE_NAME') > $BACKUP_DIR/backup$DATE.sql
```

Comment: can you share the contents of `DATABASE_USER` in your `.env` file?

Comment: currently it's "DATABASE_USER=openUser"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because on your host machine (i.e., your laptop) does not have `DATABASE_USER` defined in your environment.  Therefore, when you go to type:

```
docker exec -t db <blah> "$DATABASE_USER"
```

variable expansion occurs and $DATABASE_USER is replaced by `<null>`.  Since this causes `pg_dump` to think no user is provided, then it is assumed that the current OS user (`root` user inside the `db` container) is to be used as the DB user.

Using the `-U $(sudo docker...$DATABASE_USER)` works is because you are passing in the `$` in a way that bash doesn't expand it.  Therefore:

```
$ cat .env 
DATABASE_USER=foo

$ docker exec -it mycontainer echo "$DATABASE_USER"


$ docker exec -it mycontainer bash -c "echo $DATABASE_USER"


$ docker exec -it mycontainer bash -c "echo \$DATABASE_USER"
foo
```

Likewise, I believe if you escape the `$`, your `pg_dump` call should work.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)